# How do I retrieve the value of my key button and row in v-for using Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I trying to learn now to use it. I have 3X3 structure of buttons
I have the following sample code:

```
<template v-for="row in 3">
      <div class="row" :key="row">
        <button @click="nextPlayer(button, row)" v-for="button in 3" :key="indexByrow(button, row)" :value="squares[indexByrow(button, row)]" class="square" style="width:40px;height:40px;"></button>
      </div>
    </template>
```

When I click, I want to pass the button and row to nextPlayer(button, row), and the indexByrow(button, row) to use those values in the methods, but I don't seem to have any values. My main goal is to change the value name when I click on it.

Comment: What `indexByrow(button, row)` and `squares` will return ? Can you please add details in your question. for me it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the below changes

```
<template v-for="(row, indx) in 3">
      <div class="row" :key="indx">
        <button @click="nextPlayer(button, row)" v-for="(button, indexer) in 3" :key="indexer" :value="squares[indexByrow(button, row)]" class="square" style="width:40px;height:40px;"></button>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Not sure if `indexByrow` is a computed property or method.
You need to modify the logic in `indexByrow` as well based on the above changes